# Hive 2.0.0 not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, derby

hive.log

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Table/View 'DBS' does not exist.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:?]



tions. Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables"
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:553) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:720) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:740) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setMetaStoreSchemaVersion(ObjectStore.java:7294) ~[hive-exec-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7188) ~[hive-exec-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]


javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error executing SQL query "select "DB_ID" from "DBS"".
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:388) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:213) ~[datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar:?]
```

Comment: Your Metastore is corrupt or missing. DBS is a tables located in the hive metastore. Check if your metastore exists and is reachable.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, metastore is currently not available.

Comment: @Daniel I am getting the same exception but i have tables in MetaStore.